# Mocking an ITable using RhinoMocks for nunit testing

Tags: c#, linq, nunit, rhino-mocks, itable

I have an interface against which I run a linq to sql query:

```
public interface IMyDataContext : IDisposable
{
    ITable<MyTable> GetMyTable();
}
```

On this interface, I am running a linq query:

```
var results = from table1 in _MyDataContext.GetMyTable() 
    group table1 by table1.Column1 into myGroup
    orderby myGroup.Count() descending 
    select new
    {
        Column1 = myGroup.Key,
        Count = myGroup.Count()
    };
```

The query is running fine. Where I am stuck is while writing unit tests. 
How to get the function GetMyTable() return a mocked object with some fake data, around the todo here:

```
public class MockMyContextWrapper : IMyDataContext
{
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public ITable<MyTable> GetMyTable()
        {
            var table = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ITable<MyTable>>();

            //todo: code to return something so that the linq query fired on this table works

            return table;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you probably want to generate a mock of IMyDataContext rather than doing your own implementation for the test only.

On the IMyDataContext mock, you can setup expectations like this:

```
var dataContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyDataContext>();
var table = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ITable<MyTable>>();
dataContext.Expect(x => x.GetMyTable()).Return(table);
```

You can setup expectations on the table mock as well. Alternatively you can create a new instance of a class implementing the ITable interface filling this instance with in-memory test data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know linq-to-sql and I don't know `ITable`. But when I look at this interface, I really doubt if you should mock it. It is much too complicated. Mocking it could end up in writing a whole database simulator, which definitively doesn't make sense. The unit tests should always be as simple as possible.

I would recommend to use a real class that implements `ITable`. To make it clear: don't write your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`ITable` contains 3 different interfaces: `IEnumerable`, `IQueryable` and the other stuff in `ITable`. As all you do is query the table you could use an `IQueryable` instead and pass it to the mock/stub:

```
 IQueryable<MyTable> testTable = new[]{new MyTable{…}, new MyTable{…}, …, new MyTable{…}}.AsQueryable();
 myMock.Stub(x => x.GetMyTable()).Return(testTable);
```

each `new MyTable{…}` would represent a row in the table.

If/once you need the full `ITable` interface e.g. because you want to add or delete rows from the table you will want to create your own abstract class TestableTable you can extend `List` (that way it already implements `IEnumerable`) and offer all the `IQueryable`-methods by:

```
 public SomeType SomeMethodFromIQueryable(…)
 {
      return this.AsQueryable().SomeMthodFromIQueryable(…);
 }
```

Now only the other stuff in `ITable` is left. Those are easy to translate into `List`-Methods with exception to the `.Commit()` which you can leave abstract and then can stub it and `.AssertWasCalled(…)` it.

```
 var myMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<TestableTable<MyTable>>(){ new MyTable{…}, …};
 …
 myMock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Commit());
```

Hope that helps.

P.S.: I came across your question when I was searching for a standard solution for the same problem. Didn't find anything so I implemented this.

Answer (score 0):

This is with NSubstitute but you can adapt this for Rhino.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Your_Test_Method()
    {
        var jobs = new List<JobInstance> { new JobInstance { JobInstanceId = 123 } };
        ITable<JobInstance> jobsTable = FakeTable(jobs);
        this.wfDataContext.JobInstances.Returns(jobsTable);
        ...
    }

    /// <summary>Sets up ITable substitution</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of ITable set</typeparam>
    /// <param name="data">Data to work with</param>
    /// <returns>Substituted ITable set</returns>
    private static ITable<T> FakeTable<T>(List<T> data)
        where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> dataQueryable = data.AsQueryable();
        var fakeTable = Substitute.For<ITable<T>>();
        fakeTable.Provider.Returns(dataQueryable.Provider);
        fakeTable.Expression.Returns(dataQueryable.Expression);
        fakeTable.ElementType.Returns(dataQueryable.ElementType);
        fakeTable.GetEnumerator().Returns(dataQueryable.GetEnumerator());

        return fakeTable;
    }
```